# How to join a view with a select statement in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create a View that will produce a listing that can be used to generate monthly bills so I can create a report out of it. In this view I want the Employer Name, the employer contact name (first and last concatenated), the plan ID and description, the count of employees in that plan, the plan cost and the billing amount (count * plan cost) with the view ordered by Employer Name and PlanID. So far this is what I have:

```
CREATE VIEW VIEW15 AS (SELECT EMPLNAME, EMPLCONTACTFIRSTNAME, EMPLCONTACTLASTNAME
FROM EMPLOYERS);
SELECT PLANS.PLANID, PLNDESCRIPTION, COUNT(PLANS.CARRIER_ID), PLNCOST, (COUNT(PLANS.CARRIER_ID) * PLNCOST)
FROM PLANS, LEWISVIEW15
WHERE PLANS.PLANID = view15.planid
GROUP BY PLANS.PLANID, PLNDESCRIPTION;
```

The current error I am getting is VIEW15 not valid identifier.
It is not running and I would appreciate some guidance in the right direction to get this running.

Comment: You don't need a view to do this.  Just put the table `employers` in the `from` clause.

Comment: I forgot to mention but I'm supposed to create a view and use it later to create a report from the view. This is a homework assignment and that is what is asked for if that changes anything @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a `VIEW` and use it in the same transaction.

If this is in `SSMS`, put a `GO` between the `CREATE` and `SELECT` statements.

If this is in an app, run the scripts separately.

Answer (score 0):

Separate these two statement with a batch separator `GO` and it should work.

Also your select query must have all the columns in group by clause if they are not in any aggregate function but any one or more columns has an aggregate function applied to it in that select.

```
CREATE VIEW VIEW15 
AS 
SELECT EMPLNAME, EMPLCONTACTFIRSTNAME, EMPLCONTACTLASTNAME
FROM EMPLOYERS;
GO


SELECT PLANS.PLANID
    , PLNDESCRIPTION
    , COUNT(PLANS.CARRIER_ID)
    , PLNCOST
    , COUNT(PLANS.CARRIER_ID) * PLNCOST
FROM PLANS
INNER JOIN LEWISVIEW15 ON PLANS.PLANID = view15.planid
GROUP BY PLANS.PLANID
    , PLNDESCRIPTION
    , PLNCOST
GO
```